# Extracting Features for UNSW-NB15 Dataset from Network Traffic using Scapy

Tags: machine-learning, networking, scapy

I want to use machine learning model that is trained with UNSW-NB15 Dataset. I need to get necessary features using scapy: [text](https://cloudstor.aarnet.edu.au/plus/s/2DhnLGDdEECo4ys/download?path=%2FUNSW-NB15%20-%20CSV%20Files&files=NUSW-NB15_features.csv)

I handle the basic such as source ip, protocol etc. However I couldn't handle the whole features.

This is the code that I started to write. Is there any better option? Can I get all features?

```
import scapy.all as scapy
from datetime import datetime

start_time = None


def extract_sbytes(pkt):
    if pkt.haslayer('IP'):
        ip_len = pkt['IP'].len
        ip_header_len = pkt['IP'].ihl * 4
        if pkt.haslayer('TCP'):
            transport_len = ip_len - ip_header_len
        elif pkt.haslayer('UDP'):
            transport_len = pkt['UDP'].len - 8
        else:
            transport_len = 0
    else:
        transport_len = 0
    return transport_len

def extract_dbytes(pkt):
    if pkt.haslayer('UDP'):
        payload_len = len(pkt['UDP'].payload)
        return payload_len
    elif pkt.haslayer('TCP'):
        payload_len = len(pkt['TCP'].payload)
        return payload_len
    else:
        return 0

def extract_bytes(packet):
    sbytes = 0 
    dbytes = 0
    if packet.haslayer('TCP'):
        sbytes += len(packet['TCP'].payload)
        dbytes += len(packet['TCP'].payload)

    elif packet.haslayer('UDP'):
        sbytes += len(packet['UDP'].payload)
        dbytes += len(packet['UDP'].payload)

    return sbytes, dbytes



def extract_features(pkt):

    global start_time

    if start_time is None:
        start_time = pkt.time


    features = {}

    # Source IP
    features['srcip'] = pkt.src


    # Destination IP
    features['dstip'] = pkt.dst


    # Duration
    current_time = pkt.time
    total_duration = current_time - start_time
    features['dur'] = total_duration


    # Source Port
    if pkt.haslayer('TCP'):
        features['sport'] = pkt['TCP'].sport
    elif pkt.haslayer('UDP'):
        features['sport'] = pkt['UDP'].sport

    # Destination Port
    if pkt.haslayer('TCP'):
        features['dsport'] = pkt['TCP'].dport
    elif pkt.haslayer('UDP'):
        features['dsport'] = pkt['UDP'].dport
    else:
        features['dsport'] = 0

    # Protocol
    if pkt.haslayer('TCP'):
         features['proto'] = 'TCP'
    elif pkt.haslayer('UDP'):
         features['proto'] ='UDP'
    else:
        features['proto'] = '-'

    # State Come Back
    if pkt.haslayer('TCP'):
        tcp_flags = pkt['TCP'].flags
        #features['state'] = tcp_flags

    # Source Bytes
    #features['sbytes'] = extract_sbytes(pkt)

    # Destination Bytes
    #features['dbytes'] = extract_dbytes(pkt)


    # Come Back
    sbytes, dbytes = extract_bytes(pkt)
    #features['sbytes'] = sbytes
    #features['dbytes'] = dbytes

    return features 

def main():
    sniffer = scapy.sniff(prn=extract_features)
    for pkt in sniffer:
        print(extract_features(pkt))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```